# How to put list items of other class to array and then setText in textview

Tags: java, android

How to put the value of mylistofquestion (2nd line)  from MainActivity java class to String titleqw (7th line) in slideadapter java class

So i can pass it to TextView to settext from Array in (7th line from buttom) in slideadapter java file

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public List<String> mylistofquestion = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<String> mylistofanswer = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        slideadapter slideadapter = new slideadapter(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(slideadapter);


        myjsonrequest();


    }

    //requesting for data
    public void myjsonrequest() {
        //url to make request
        String Url = "https://learncodeonline.in/api/android/datastructure.json";

        JsonObjectRequest myjsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, Url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.i("response", "is " + response);

                        try {

                            JSONArray jsonArrayofmine = response.getJSONArray("questions");


                            Log.i("jsonarray", "is " + jsonArrayofmine);


                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayofmine.length(); i++) {
                                //taking quesstion and answer
                                JSONObject jsonObjectinarray = jsonArrayofmine.getJSONObject(i);

                                String question = jsonObjectinarray.getString("question");
                                String answer = jsonObjectinarray.getString("Answer");

                                mylistofquestion.add(i, question);
                                mylistofanswer.add(i, answer);


                            }
                            Log.i("mylistofquestion", "is " + mylistofquestion);
                            Log.i("mylistofanswer", "is " + mylistofanswer);


                            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < mylistofquestion.size(); i1++) {

                                Log.i("Value of element " + i1, mylistofquestion.get(i1));

                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //show snackbar
            }
        }

        );
        MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestque(myjsonObjectRequest);


    }
}
```

Slideadapter:

```
public class slideadapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    //list of image
    int images[] = {R.drawable.bulbblue, R.drawable.bulbgreen, R.drawable.circle, R.drawable.cross};
    //lisst of title

    // put the value of mylistofquestion from MainActivity to String titleqw

    public String[] titleqw = {"aaasdasdas", "yuyui", "third", "fourth"};
    //list of desscription
    public String[] descriptionqw = {"one", "two", "three", "four"};


    //list of background color
    public int[] backgroundColor = {
            Color.rgb(55, 55, 55),
            Color.rgb(5, 5, 35),
            Color.rgb(55, 55, 25),
            Color.rgb(85, 155, 5)
    };


    public slideadapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }


    /**
     * Return the number of views available.
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return backgroundColor.length;
    }

    /**
     * Determines whether a page View is associated with a specific key object
     * as returned by {@link #, int)}. This method is
     * required for a PagerAdapter to function properly.
     *
     * @param view   Page View to check for association with <code>object</code>
     * @param object Object to check for association with <code>view</code>
     * @return true if <code>view</code> is associated with the key object <code>object</code>
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return (view == (LinearLayout) object);
    }

    /**
     * Remove a page for the given position.  The adapter is responsible
     * for removing the view from its container, although it only must ensure
     * this is done by the time it returns from {@link #finishUpdate(ViewGroup)}.
     *
     * @param container The containing View from which the page will be removed.
     * @param position  The page position to be removed.
     * @param object    The same object that was returned by
     *                  {@link #instantiateItem(View, int)}.
     */
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }


    /**
     * Create the page for the given position.  The adapter is responsible
     * for adding the view to the container given here, although it only
     * must ensure this is done by the time it returns from
     * {@link #finishUpdate(ViewGroup)}.
     *
     * @param container The containing View in which the page will be shown.
     * @param position  The page position to be instantiated.
     * @return Returns an Object representing the new page.  This does not
     * need to be a View, but can be some other container of the page.
     */
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slide, container, false);
        LinearLayout layoutslide = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
        ImageView imgslide = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageviewofus);
        TextView txttitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.texta);
        TextView description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textb);

        layoutslide.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor[position]);
        imgslide.setImageResource(images[position]);


        //get List items in txttitle

        txttitle.setText(titleqw[position]);
        description.setText(descriptionqw[position]);
        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Here in above line i want to get that arraylist items in txttitle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: cut these two line from Mainactivity

```
  slideadapter slideadapter = new slideadapter(this);
  viewPager.setAdapter(slideadapter);
```

Step 2: paste these above two line after for loop in method myjsonrequest(like below) with some modification

```
   slideadapter slideadapter = new slideadapter(this,mylistofquestion,mylistofanswer);
   viewPager.setAdapter(slideadapter);
```

step 3: in slideadapter change constructor to this

```
public slideadapter(Context context, List<String> mylistofquestion, List<String> mylistofanswer) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mylistofquestion = mylistofquestion;
    this.mylistofanswer = mylistofanswer;
}
```

Step 4 : in slideadapter inside instantiateItem method 
replace this line

```
txttitle.setText(titleqw[position]);
```

with new below one

```
txttitle.setText(mylistofquestion.get(position));
```

Comment: error: cannot find symbol variable mylistofquestion  in step 3

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at kvadityaaz.forhitesh.com.datastructurepreparation.slideadapter.instantiateItem(slideadapter.java:122)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:1004)

Comment: In  slideadapter after Context context;  add these two line ->                                            List<String> mylistofquestion;                                                       List<String> mylistofanswer;

Answer (score 0):

You could try to put slideadapter, which actually should be "SlideAdapter" **inside** your Mainactivity.class. Otherwhise you have to work with [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) i guess..